# Print multiple multipaged files with one Printdocument

Tags: vb.net, printdocument

I want to print a list of `multipage .tiff files`. The problem i'm having is that i'm not getting multiple pages, only the first page gets 'printed'. Can someone point out to me what i'm exactly doing wrong?

```
Private Sub docPrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    For Each filName As String In fileN
        Dim m_Image As Image = Image.FromFile(filName)
        Dim pc As Integer = 0
        Dim currPage As Integer = 0

        pc = m_Image.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)

        While (currPage < pc)
            m_Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, currPage)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_Image, e.PageBounds) 'Most likely the problem lies here

            currPage = currPage + 1
            e.HasMorePages = true

        End While
    Next
    e.HasMorePages = false
 End Sub
```

Some explanation of the variables:

```
fileN: List of paths to my files
pc: pagecount/framecount of the current .tiff
currPage: index of the active frame in the current .tiff
```

**My Ultimate goal:** to show a series (list) of multi-framed .tiffs in a print-preview.

Comment: why set `e.HasMorePages = false`

Comment: Other wise it keeps on adding pages using the method docPrintPage. e.HasMorePages has to be set to false in the end.One of the many references:  Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/733680/Printing-and-Previewing-multiple-pages-in-Csharp

Comment: what do you want exactly? print a single tiff page on every printed page? because PrintPage event prints a single page but you are trying to print multiple tiff page and then exit specifying that HasMorePages = False, which is not correct.

Comment: Indeed my ultime goal is to print a single tiff per page. Each frame inside a tiff is A4-sized. The issue lies within the existance of multiple files and multiple frames and show it in a printpreview. Showing one multiple frame .tiff isn't the problem, its showing a list

Comment: Remove that code and try

Comment: Tried it, it goes to printing into infinity. e.HasMorePages = false is needed in order for the printdocument to understand that there aren't any pages after the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem thanks to the following post:

[Thank you very very much Tezzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819883/3099117)

First create the following class-variables

```
Private fileCount As Integer = 0 // Index of the current file/Image
Private currPage As Integer = 0 // Current Page in the current file/Image
Private pCount As Integer = 0 // PageCount in the current file/Image
Private currImage As Image // My Current Image
```

Create a new PrintDocument (in some function) and assign it to PrintPreviewDialog

```
    Dim vPrintDoc As New PrintDocument
    vPrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False

    AddHandler vPrintDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf docPrintPage
    AddHandler vPrintDoc.BeginPrint, AddressOf docBeginprint


    Dim i As PrintPreviewDialog = New PrintPreviewDialog
    i.Document = vPrintDoc
    i.ShowDialog()
```

Inside your method `docBeginPrint` you set your classvariables (declared before) to stats of the first (if present)

```
Private Sub docBeginprint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs)

    If fileN.Count > 0 Then
        currPage = 0
        currImage = Image.FromFile(fileN.Item(0))
        pCount = currImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
    End If

End Sub
```

'Then in your docPrintPage you start printing

```
Private Sub docPrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    currImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, currPage) 'Set the Active Frame of your image to that of the following frame that needs to printed.

    Using st As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream() 'We use a memory stream to print Images in order to avoid a bug inside the e.graphics.

        currImage.Save(st, ImageFormat.Bmp)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromStream(st), Bitmap)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)
        bmp.Dispose()

    End Using

    currPage += 1 'Current page is printed, increase index with 1

    If currPage < pCount Then 'Are there any further pages in the current image?
        e.HasMorePages = True 'yes continue printing
    Else 'no 
        If fileCount = (fileN.Count - 1) Then 'Hase the list anymore files?
            e.HasMorePages = False 'No - stop printing all together
        Else 'yes
            currPage = 0 'Set your index for the current page back to first
            fileCount += 1 'Increase the index of the current file
            currImage = Image.FromFile(fileN.Item(fileCount)) 'Load the next image (Perhaps if-statements is desired to avoid Null-Reference)
            pCount = currImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page) 'Load the pagecount of the current image

            e.HasMorePages = True 'continue printing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this may be of some use to other people.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pseudo-code (sorry but I can't recreate your situation):

```
Dim intFileToPrint as Integer = 0
Dim intPageToPrint as Integer = 0
Dim intPagePrinted as Integer = 0

Private Sub PrintPreview()

    For intFileToPrint = 0 To fileN.Count - 1

        intPageToPrint = Image.FromFile(fileN(intFileToPrint)).GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
        intPagePrinted = 0

        AddHandler yourPrintDocument.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintFile
        yourPrintDocument.Print()

    End Sub

End Sub

Private PrintFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim imgToPrint as Image = Image.FromFile(fileN(intFileToPrint)).SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, intPagePrinted)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgToPrint, e.PageBounds)

    intPagePrinted = intPagePrinted + 1

    If intPagePrinted < intPageToPrint then e.HasMorePages = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty much what i was searching for! :) Your code gave me an excellent idea to try out!

Comment: It did! Will post my adjusted code in an instant :)